# Mac OS Terminal - setting path to exe

Tags: bash, osx-yosemite

I have a TrueType font file (.ttf) I want to modify by using "ttx" exe to insert a digital signature (from file dsig.ttx). I have been using a successful routine for some time but now the path to the ttx exe has changed. Entering "which ttx" finds /Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx, so I guess that's the one to use, but entering the full routine now finds another copy of ttx in the Python Folder!

Here's what I do:

1. which ttx
2. RTN
3. drag ttx to Terminal
4. enter -m
5. drag the .ttf file to Terminal
6. drag dsig.ttx file to Terminal
7. RTN

Here's the result

```
Last login: Wed Apr  8 17:12:55 on ttys001 
Adrians-iMac:~ adrianshome$ which ttx
/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx 
Adrians-iMac:~ adrianshome$ -m /Users/adrianshome/Documents/\SASSOON/Sassoon\Fonts\ DEV/Current\ Versions/font+installer\ builds/S9000\ Pinyin/New\ Family/FolderTest/SassoonInftPY.ttf /Applications/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx
-bash: -m: command not found Adrians-iMac:~ adrianshome$
```

How can I get Terminal to use this path: `/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx`

Comment: can you format a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

`which ttx` just prints the path to the terminal, it doesn't set the executable of your next command. What you should do, after your step 2, is to copy the output and paste it to the terminal (in general you also have to quote it if it has whitespace in it), i.e., you should type

```
/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx -m
```

before you do your steps 5, 6, and 7. The full command will be

```
/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx -m /Users/adrianshome/Documents/\SASSOON/Sassoon\Fonts\ DEV/Current\ Versions/font+installer\ builds/S9000\ Pinyin/New\ Family/FolderTest/SassoonInftPY.ttf /Applications/FDK/Tools/osx/ttx
```

Comment: Thanks, but following those steps (pasting the which ttx path) still results in the wrong ttx exe being used, so after parsing I get a file with zero bytes. How do I ensure Terminal uses the correct ttx exe?